# Embeded youtube video not playing

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api

I have a YouTube video that was working fine in last month but now doesn't play in iOS 6.

This is my code I have tried. It's correctly streaming video from YouTube but when I click the play button it doesn't play the video and shows error message:

> This video is currently unavailable

But this video is available in YouTube and playing well. Is there any update in Apple?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 55, 500, 500);

    NSString *strurl=@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/x1g53j4BY9Y?feature=player_embedded";

    NSLog(@"stringwithurl===%@",strurl);

    NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: transparent;\
                          color: blue;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <embed id=\"yt\" height=\"500\" width=\"500\"src=\"%@\ type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"></embed>\
                          </body></html>",strurl];
    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [webview sizeToFit];
    webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [webview loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is happening yet, but if you clear Cookies on the iphone it seems to fix the issue in my experience. It's really hard to troubleshoot because of this - I'm not sure what cookie information is the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used this pod:

https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

Its so easy to use.

Example:

```
LBYouTubePlayerViewController* controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerViewController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fTIhC1WSew&list=FLEYfH4kbq85W_CiOTuSjf8w&feature=mh_lolz"] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
controller.view.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];
```

Enjoy it.

Comment: Its working but it display only a few seconds and after that it hides automatically and video doesn't play

Answer (score 0):

Use following code its working fine for me.

```
NSString *strurl=@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/x1g53j4BY9Y?feature=player_embedded";

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes, width = 320\"/></head><body style=\"background:#00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"320\" height=\"180\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height='%0.0f'></embed></object></div></body></html>", strurl, strurl,self.videoWebView.frame.size.height];

NSString *finalHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,self.videoWebView.frame.size.width,
             self.videoWebView.frame.size.height,urlString];

[videoWebView loadHTMLString:finalHtml baseURL:nil];
```